# Minecraft bukkit plugin for maintaining a separate resettable mining world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

A friend told me that he had played on a server that had a plugin or something that maintained a separate world he could teleport into, which was rich in minerals.

Every so often, that world was dropped, and thus recreated, and was ever-fresh every day with new minerals.

Does anyone know the name of that plugin, or how to set up this system?

We have bukkit on our server, but not much else other than "bukkit essentials".

Comment: @fredley will probably know

Comment: If all you want is a resettable mining area, I'd recommend looking into [PrisonMine](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/prisonmine/).

Comment: @Schism That sounds like more an answer than a comment!

Comment: The usual way would be to get a Bukkit plugin which does that. The "fun" way would be to get Multiverse, setup the mining world, and then delete the contents of the world directory via a cronjob (and maybe restarting the server). That way the server will be forced to regenerate the world.

Comment: Was this the `BuxVille` server by chance?  They have such an auto-reset mining world called the `Ether`.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds a lot like the [Mystcraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/918541-151-mystcraft-0103/) mod. It's not a Bukkit mod though; it's a Forge mod.

PS: I should warn you that moving your world from a Bukkit server to a Mojang server (which Forge runs on) can affect your world (not necessarily, but it's known to happen). I'd recommend you looking into [Feed The Beast](http://feed-the-beast.com/) and their modpacks, all based on Forge, and some of them including Mystcraft (and lots more).

Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, though it's an easy mistake to make. Making a separate world is *easy*, and could be done on Bukkit years before Mystcraft existed. What's hard, and is the core of this question, is how to make a world delete/reset on a timer.

Comment: and respawn all players back into the overworld on the reset

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly that using Multiverse, WorldGuard and WorldEdit.

To recreate the world:
 - Delete the world (mv delete worldName)
 - Create a new world (mv create worldName NORMAL)
 - Redefine the protected area (rg redefine ....)
 - Paste the spawn if you have one

IMPORTANT: You should not regenerate using the same seed, becouse the minerals will be placed in the same place, and users could abuse it.